# How to change UIProgressView color while Progress Changes

Tags: ios, uicolor, uiprogressview

I want to change my UIProgressView progress color while the progress changes. So basically it starts white and goes getting blue while it approaches the end.

here's my code:

```
-(void)changeSendProgProgress:(float)progress
{


    CGFloat redBlueValue = 255 - (255*progress);

    UIColor *colorProg = [UIColor colorWithRed:redBlueValue green:redBlueValue blue:255 alpha:1.0];

    [sendProgress setProgressTintColor:colorProg];
    [sendProgress setProgress:progress];


}
```

the only problem is that the progress color doesn't change, it stays white all the way to the end.
Why it doesn`t change? 
Should I use a UIThreading like  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ?

Comment: Values are from `0.0` to `1.0`. Divide your `redBlueValue` by `255.0` and set your blue value to `1.0`.

Comment: It did work! Lack of reading method documentation... =(

Comment: This is the typical parameter issue that can be seen in loads of objective-c code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are actually setting integer values that are equal or smaller than 255. Regarding Apple's documentation, all the parameters should be in CGFloat type between 0.0 to 1.0.

Please kindly consider this link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian MacDonald said, the values of [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue: alpha:] goes from 0.0 to 1.0

so heres the correct code:

```
-(void)changeSendProgProgress:(float)progress
{


    CGFloat redBlueValue = (255 - (255*progress)) /255.0;

    UIColor *colorProg = [UIColor colorWithRed:redBlueValue green:redBlueValue blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    [sendProgress setProgressTintColor:colorProg];
    [sendProgress setProgress:progress];


}
```

Comment: `1.0 - progress` would be simpler than `(255 - 255*progress)/255`, no?